# Difficulty with power analysis

Tags: binomial-distribution, statistical-power, equivalence

I need to estimate sample size for an experiment but I am not very knowledgeable about power analysis.

In my experiment, I am asking if a user can notice the two possible states of a system. I present each user a series of tests with a sequence of $k$ states, randomly selected. The user answers with $A$ and $B$ choices for each state. So for example if we present a user the sequence $ABBBABAA$ and he/she correctly identifies the sequence, we call it a pass, otherwise a fail.

Our hypothesis is that users are just guessing and they cannot separate the two states. If users are just guessing the chances that they pick up the correct sequence is $1/2^{k}$ which becomes smaller and smaller as $k$ increases. However, as $k$ increases, tests become longer and longer which makes them less practical. Also increases the risk that "by chance", users get a fail since they just got tired at the end of the test.

My question is how should I relate the sample size $N$, length of the sequence $k$ and the power of the test ($\alpha$ and $\beta$).

Answer (score 1):

There are $N$ users. Each user produces a value from a $X \sim \text{Bin}(k, \pi)$ random variable, where $\pi$ is the true success probability.

You want to test
$$
\text{H}_0: \pi = 0.5 \quad \text{VS} \quad \text{H}_1: \pi \neq 0.5
$$

$$
$$

A quick, pragmatic way to determine the power of that test is to

- fix values for $N$, $k$, and $\pi$,
- randomly draw many samples with those parameters,
- perform the hypothesis testing for each sample,
- compute the proportion of times $\text{H}_0$ is rejected (this is the power!),
- play with the parameters $N$, $K$, and $\pi$.

**edit**
I have Just realised that it is here assumed that the $k$ results are available for each user. If it is not the case, then the same idea applies using a Bernoulli distribution and $0.5^k$.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try to use this formulation to run some simulations. However, I don't understand intuitively how $k$ should affect power. Any insights?